# Golang Broken Import

Tags: go, grpc-go

### I got an error when trying import this package:

```
"github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway"
"github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2"
"google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc"
"google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go"
```

the errors show:

> could not import
> github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway (no
> required module provides package
> "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway")

the errors are the same **no required module provides package**

### here's my go-env:

```
GO111MODULE="on"

GOARCH="amd64"

GOBIN="/usr/local/go/bin"

GOCACHE="/home/servumtopia/.cache/go-build"

GOENV="/home/servumtopia/.config/go/env"

GOEXE=""

GOEXPERIMENT=""

GOFLAGS

GOHOSTARCH="amd64"

GOHOSTOS="linux"

GOINSECURE=""

GOMODCACHE="/home/servumtopia/go/pkg/mod"

GONOPROXY=""

GONOSUMDB=""

GOOS="linux"

GOPATH="/home/servumtopia/go"

GOPRIVATE=""

GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"

GOROOT="/usr/local/go"

GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"

GOTMPDIR=""

GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"

GOVCS=""

GOVERSION="go1.19"

GCCGO="gccgo"

GOAMD64="v1"

AR="ar"

CC="gcc"

CXX="g++"

CGO_ENABLED="1"

GOMOD="/home/servumtopia/CODE/GO/sqlc/go.mod"

GOWORK=""

CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"

CGO_CPPFLAGS=""

CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"

CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"

CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"

PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"

GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build2576989244=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

### the code:

```
//go:build tools
// +build tools

package tools

import (
    _ "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway"
    _ "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2"
    _ "google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc"
    _ "google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go"
)
```

---

### file structure:

```
├── api
├── db
│   ├── migration
│   ├── mock
│   ├── queries
│   └── sqlc
├── gapi
├── pb
├── proto
│   └── google
│       └── api
├── token
├── tools
└── util
```

### Explanation:

**the go.mod file were adding the imported package**

```
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2 v2.11.3
google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc v1.2.0
google.golang.org/protobuf v1.28.1
```

**i try to import the package in the main.go file and i got this error when i run the code.**

```
main.go:23:2: import "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway" is a program, not an importable package
main.go:24:2: import "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2" is a program, not an importable package
main.go:25:2: import "google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc" is a program, not an importable package
main.go:26:2: import "google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go" is a program, not an importable package
```

Comment: go mod tidy -v  - tried this?

Comment: already, the error still exist

Answer (score 2):

Those packages you're trying to import are a `main` package. You cannot import a `main` package as they are supposed to be compiled into programs (and you need a `main` package of your own).

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/tree/master/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway), you'll see that this package has only a `main.go` file, which there's nothing that you can even use inside (it only has two non-exported functions).

The same is true for the other packages in question.

The best I could find was an official documentation on how to create a `main.go` file: https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/tutorials/creating_main.go/ -- I haven't read it thoroughly, tough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, yes i know those package where main package, i think (my assumption) the idea of importing that file is to get the import package from those "main" package, the problem so far i found is i can compile the code and running it without any problem, so i think it's like a dummy error or code-bug on my code, so far what i know just that. Thanks Mate :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you initialize go module? If you haven't try these steps.

### 1. Create a module

```
go mod init github.com/youraccount/yourpackge
```

### 2. Create main.go

You already have your code here

### 2. Run `go mod tidy` from project root

```
go mod tidy
```

This should fix your imports.

You can individually `go get` them as well. Run these commands from your project root (where your go.mod is).

```
go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go
go get github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway
go get google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
go get github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2
```

Comment: yes i already create my module and also i already do the go get command but still error still there, thanks for the reply.